# users ending up with the same id.... possible race condition?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, race-condition

I have inherited a piece of code from a Laravel 5 codebase that essentially takes an svg symbol, allows you to add effects and text, and saves it as an SVG that gets linked to a user's account. The system works, but every once and a while you will see that 2 customers will end up with the same "newAvatar->id" linked to their account. I have been scratching my brain as to why but can't seem to figure it out.

Would this be caused by some sort of race condition? Do I need to put a semaphore or mutex of some sort around this code?

```
        public function createAvatar()
        {
            $status = 400;
            $_data = array('error' => 'Unknown Error');

            if (Input::has('avatar_svg'))
            {
                    $svg = Input::get('avatar_svg');

                  $newAvatar = Avatar::create([
                      'svg_content' => $svg,
                  ]);

                  if ($newAvatar) {
                      $status = 200;
                      $_data = array('avatarID' => $newAvatar->id);
                  }
           }

      //data is sent back as JSON to be processed by AngularJS                   
            return Response::json([
                'data' => $_data,                               
            ], $status, array(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
```

Comment: Looks like the same `symbol_ID` was passed to the PHP script. The problem is probably with the generation of `symbol_ID`. Can you post that code here?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. the Symbol ID doesn't actually do anything and is essentially legacy code that I should have removed from the post.  I will do this now to prevent confusion.

Comment: Is your `avatar` table's `id` column auto-incrementing? If so, I can't see why `$newAvatar->id` would have the same value as another.

Comment: What DB is in use? MySQL InnoDB?

Comment: The answer seems to be that users managed to find a path through the site that would make this possible. Thanks to all for the help though.

Comment: Your problem isn't solved by semaphores or mutexes, but by constructing the database model properly. In your case, two people can't have the same `symbol_id`. That's a clear sign your `symbol_id` should be unique among users. It's quite trivial to add a unique constraint to your db, preventing more than 1 person to have a `symbol_id` assigned to them.

Comment: Symbol_id does not have to be unique as it's just the base image used by the avatar and can be used by many people. It's also not used anymore, as mentioned above. This code base is a bit messy

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the help, but the answer was that users managed to find a path through the software that was never intended to be taken or possible.

It's amazing the things that people find when code goes live